I notice that the username I put for my VS Code username is not matching and might be abbreviated
enter image description herePS C:\Users\julia>
is what it says when I enter any terminal or vs code. I am trying to change my username to something different but haven't found anything that works. Is it because when I download VS Code it just uses the name in the laptop? Let me know if there is a way I can resolve this issue
I tried syncing Github and Gmail but it still says "julia" as the username instead of anything else I put.

I'm not a VSCode user, but you're mixing various types of (user) names here.
The C:\Users\julia> bit refers to your user directory on the machine you run VSCode on, you cannot change that in vscode, it is your home directory on that machine. You could change it by changing your Windows login account name (assuming you're under Windows).
The screenshot seems to be about Profiles, not user names. Profiles in an IDE typically have nothing to do with github usernames.
So if you want to change the C:\Users\julia bit specifically, you need to change the account name of your windows (or other operating system) user outside of VSCode and then run VSCode with that changed user. However, that being said, I don't see why you would want to do so. Unless it is for screenshots that particular part is not visible for outsiders - if you want to change a username that appears some place else (github perhaps?) then you likely should open a separate question that clearly identifies what you need to be different.
However, if it is about the github account, then there might already exist answers here. Here is a related one for example: Changing the Git user inside Visual Studio Code
